# getting compiler error (invalid identifier)

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

As said above, in my following code I get an compiler error telling me there is an invalid identifier. I don't really see the problem, basically it is a very easy code. The problem should be in the lines using the backcolor-Function.

```
Sub addmaterial()

Dim AMU As UserForm
Set AMU = AddMaterialUserform1
Dim SCU As ComboBox
Set SCU = AMU.SelectComboBoxUserform
Dim APCU As ComboBox
Set APCU = AddMaterialUserform1.AddedPropertiesComboBoxUserform
Dim TextBoxObject As Combobox
Dim i As Integer


SCU.AddItem "Material"
SCU.AddItem "Material Group"

APCU.BorderColor.ColorIndex = 15

For i = 1 To 12
    TextBoxObject = "Textbox" & i
    AMU.TextBoxObject.BackColor.ColorIndex = 15
Next

AMU.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: if think you can also use "UserForm1.TextBox1.BackColor = &HFF00&" and get the color from the properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to assign a String to an Object

```
TextBoxObject = "Textbox" & i
```

You can use the `AMU.Controls`- Collection

```
Set TextBoxObject = AMU.Controls("Textbox" & i)
```

If you don't have the reference just the Name.

Or if there is no Collection on other Objects have a look at

```
CallByName(Object As Object, ProcName As String, _
           CallType As VbCallType, Args() As Variant)`
```

`.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem using the AMU.Controls - Collection

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim TextBoxObject As String
 AMU.TextBoxObject.BackColor.ColorIndex = 15
```

At a guess it doesn't like you declaring a string variable as the same name as a text box

Comment: Right! I changed the Dim to Combobox. Sadly, the problem is stil there.

Comment: I think ColorIndex is the problem because this does not exist.

Comment: yes, you're right @storax do you know if there is another possibilty to set a color than RGB(x,x,x)?

Comment: D'oh! Yes your right - Backcolor takes a RGB value so that line should be AMU.Textboxobject.backcolor = 8421504